# Can Golang test scripts issue warnings rather than errors?

Tags: testing, go

I have a set of tests that may not pass due to external 3rd party issues.
I don't want the test to fail when this condition occurs but would like to be made aware.

Issuing a `t.Errorf()` is not idea because it will stop all subsequent tests. Is there some kind of "Warning" I can trigger that the test script would post and then continue with the remainder of the tests?

Comment: You can always substitute those calls for `Logf` instead but that requires using the verbose flag to see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The go test tool is like the compiler. To the compiler something either compiles or doesn't, there are no warnings. I think the closest thing you're going to get is to use [t.Skip](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Skip). It will stop execution of the current test but does not mark it as failed. You will not see anything in the output of `go test` however so you have to use `go test -v`.

Here's an example package that uses `t.Skipf` if the `addExternal` function fails.

```
package app

import "testing"

func add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func addExternal(a, b int) int {
    return 4
}

func divide(a, b int) int {
    return a / b
}

func TestThing(t *testing.T) {
    got := add(1, 2)
    want := 3
    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("add(1, 2) = %d, want %d", got, want)
    }
}

func TestExternalThing(t *testing.T) {
    got := addExternal(3, 4)
    want := 7
    if got != want {
        t.Skipf("addExternal(3, 4) = %d, want %d", got, want)
    }
}

func TestAnotherThing(t *testing.T) {
    got := divide(6, 3)
    want := 2
    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("divide(6, 3) = %d, want %d", got, want)
    }
}
```

And here's the output from running that. Note the return status is 0 and the package is considered to have passed

```
$ go test -v
=== RUN   TestThing
--- PASS: TestThing (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestExternalThing
--- SKIP: TestExternalThing (0.00s)
        app_test.go:29: addExternal(3, 4) = 4, want 7
=== RUN   TestAnotherThing
--- PASS: TestAnotherThing (0.00s)
PASS
ok      github.com/jcbwlkr/app  0.006s
$ echo $?
0
```

Note though that if I change the `t.Skipf` to `t.Errorf` or `t.Fatalf` I get this output

```
$ go test -v
=== RUN   TestThing
--- PASS: TestThing (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestExternalThing
--- FAIL: TestExternalThing (0.00s)
        app_test.go:29: addExternal(3, 4) = 4, want 7
=== RUN   TestAnotherThing
--- PASS: TestAnotherThing (0.00s)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/jcbwlkr/app  0.005s
$ echo $?
1
```

The other tests in the package are still ran. If I was testing multiple packages such as with `go test -v ./...` I believe they would also still be ran.